# Using dozer mapper in Apache Camel routes

Tags: apache-camel, dozer

Can any one provide me an end to end example of using Dozer mapper in Apache camel routes.
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a basic example can be found in the component unit tests...

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-dozer/src/test/

Comment: just an update, <converBodyTo type="org.pkg.class"/> would automatically convert a given type in a camel route provided  below is registered <bean id="dozerConverterLoader" class="org.apache.camel.converter.dozer.DozerTypeConverterLoader" />